# How to view Crypto Wallet transactions simplified like bank statement

Tags: transactions, polygon

Is there any tool that I can use to make sense of my Crypto Wallet transactions? A human-understandable simple ledger where I can see what happened(amount In/amount Out/amount Swapped), date, addresses, balance left, fees, etc at transaction level.

Similar to like:

```
Date, This came in/That went out/This swapped(converted) to That,Token/Currency, Txn Fees, Balance Start, Balance End, etc
```

Just like a bank account statement.

Here is one [tool](https://medium.com/shapelabs/how-to-make-sense-of-your-ethereum-transactions-4759065fb654) that is obsolete now. Any help is appreciated.